# Stuck on this question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Water fills a tank at an increasing rate of 50 litres during the first hour, 75 litres during the second hour, 100 litres during the third hour and so on. The size of the tank is 16 x 6 x 3. All dimensions in metres. i am stuck trying to figure out how long it takes to fill the tank to the nearest hour.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: How many liters is the tank?  Can you write a nice expression for the number of liters the tank receives in $n$ hours?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

1. The volume of the tank is $$V=16\cdot 6\cdot3\ \mathrm{m}^3=288000\ \mathrm{l}$$
2. The water flow after $j$ hours is $$F_j=50+25\cdot j$$
3. The volume filled after $j$ hours is $$V_j=F_0+F_1+...+F_{j-1}=50+(50+25)+...+(50+25(j-1))$$
   There is a simple formula to calculate the sum in terms of $j$. Then try to find the value of $j$ for which $V_j=V$.